How do I append an option argument to the flag without spaces?
I am writing a program manual in mdoc(7). One example of my programs has this synopsis:

parsrc.sh [-lf<s>] [CSV_file]


Taken from ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/parsrc.sh
For example if you run parsrc.sh -lf - then <s> is a null string. If you run parsrc.sh -lfEOL - then <s> is EOL.
I wish I could render it like:

parsrc.sh -lfs [CSV_file]

And I tried with \&:
.Dd $Mdocdate$
.Dt PARSRC.SH 1
.Os
.Sh NAME
.Nm parsrc.sh
.Nd CSV parser
.Sh SYNOPSIS
.Nm parsrc.sh
.Op Fl lf \& Ar s
.Op Ar CSV_file

Then I got this rendered:

Or with mandoc -Thtml:
<section class="Sh">
<h1 class="Sh" id="SYNOPSIS"><a class="permalink" href="#SYNOPSIS">SYNOPSIS</a></h1>
<table class="Nm">
  <tr>
    <td><code class="Nm">parsrc.sh</code></td>
    <td>[<code class="Fl">-lf</code> <code class="Fl">-</code>
      <var class="Ar">s</var>] [<var class="Ar">CSV_file</var>]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</section>

What is the appropriate way to realize it?
Also this idea should be useful for example:

files

if file is an argument.

According to mdoc(7):

Ns
Suppress a space between the output of the preceding macro and the following text or macro. Following invocation, input is interpreted as normal text just like after an No macro.

For example:
.Fl lf Ns Ar s

My manual should be:
.Dd $Mdocdate$
.Dt PARSRC.SH 1
.Os
.Sh NAME
.Nm parsrc.sh
.Nd CSV parser
.Sh SYNOPSIS
.Nm parsrc.sh
.Op Fl lf Ns Ar s
.Op Ar CSV_file

It outputs:
<section class="Sh">
<h1 class="Sh" id="SYNOPSIS"><a class="permalink" href="#SYNOPSIS">SYNOPSIS</a></h1>
<table class="Nm">
  <tr>
    <td><code class="Nm">parsrc.sh</code></td>
    <td>[<code class="Fl">-lf</code><var class="Ar">s</var>]
      [<var class="Ar">CSV_file</var>]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</section>

